# PHP for-loop not working

Tags: php, for-loop, syntax-error, copy-paste

I have this for-loop in PHP which isn't working:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i = $i + 10) {
    echo $i;
}
```

and this one that does work:

```
  for ($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i = $i + 10) {
echo $i;
}
```

I'm sure that I'm missing something, but they appear to be exactly identical to each other. What's the difference? The first one was copied and pasted, the second one typed by myself. What's the difference? Why isn't the second one working? The error is this:

This is the error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ';' on line 12

Line 12 is the first line of the code in the sample (it's from a larger script).

Comment: The loops are exactly the same

Comment: @PedroLobito so why does the first one work and the second one not?

Comment: Take a look at the code immediately before line 12. The problem could the there but the compiler doesn't recognize a problem until it gets to your loop.

Comment: @gxclarke thanks! just found the error- it's the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The loops are exactly the same and [they both work](http://ideone.com/C0r41w), you must have any other error on the script, although, you can use :

```
$i+=10;
```

instead of:

```
$i = $i + 10
```

Comment: Thanks! turns out it was a compiler issue.